# evenly spacing <table> with Twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I create a table with html and twitter bootstrap. However the table entries are a bit jumbled together. I was wondering how I can align them to be evenly spaced

```
<table class="table">
  <tr class="ass testPageRow">
    <td id="tp1">1</td>
    <td id="tp4">4</td>
    <td id="tp5">5</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="ass testPageRow">
    <td id="tp12">12</td>
    <td id="tp13">13</td>
    <td id="tp14">14</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="ass testPageRow">
    <td id="tp14TTU">14TTU</td>
    <td id="tp15">15</td>
    <td id="tp16">16</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="ass testPageRow">
    <td id="tp18">18</td>
    <td id="tp20">20</td>
    <td id="tp21">21</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="ass testPageRow">
    <td id="tp22">22</td>
    <td id="tp23">23</td>
    <td id="tp24">24</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="ass testPageRow">
    <td id="tp25">25</td>
    <td id="tp26">26</td>
    <td id="tp27">27</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="ass testPageRow">
    <td id="tp28">28</td>
    <td id="tp29">29</td>
    <td id="tp30">30</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the width of the `<td>` elements based on the number of columns in the table.

```
table {
    width:100%;
}

td {
    width:33%; // 3 evenly sized columns
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jv3hr7LL/